# Fixed income data online

Tags: python, finance, google-finance, stock

I am looking for a resource to download fixed income data online, much like there is access to stock data from yahoo. At the very least I'd like the treasury bonds.

I use python, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for prices, auction results, TAQ? In some ways the data on FI is richer

Comment: Please contact me offline at eugene at webservius dot com - I may have a solution for you

Comment: Can you indicate what kind of precision and history you’re looking for? Suitable for what tasks?

Answer (score 2):

Treasury bond price history is usually proprietary (Tradeweb, Bloomberg, CRSP), but yield history is published.

For example:

http://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/feds/2006/

Number 2006-28: The U.S. Treasury Yield Curve: 1961 to the Present. Refet S. Gurkaynak, Brian Sack, and Jonathan H. Wright. This is accompanied by a history of yields and the parameters of a fitted smooth curve model.

Another free source of yields and other data is the Federal Reserve H.15 publication. http://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/update/

Yahoo Finance currently displays treasury bond prices from ValuBond.  http://bonds.yahoo.com/ But these are crap – you can easily verify the yields are out of date.

FINRA offers corporate and treasury bond prices through a web interface. I looked at a couple treasury prices and they appear to be 2 days old. http://cxa.marketwatch.com/finra/MarketData/

(The FINRA yield summary seems up to date for on the run issues – different from the H.15 which is constant maturity.)

For corporate bonds, TRACE is your friend. Go here: http://cxa.marketwatch.com/finra/BondCenter/TraceDownloads.aspx

Comment: Looks like H15 data is much more difficult to automatically download now. They changed the access method.

Answer (score 1):

That will be hard to impossible.  Little of this is exchange-traded (i.e. public) and even if it were, exchanges are unlikely to give data away for free.  Sales of data now comprise more than half of total revenue for a number of exchanges.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/rates/index.html).